# How to let the user specify a variable in embed?

Tags: function, variables, discord.py, bots, embed

Tried to pass a variable entered by the user, but nothing happens

Tried to pass only in description and field_value!

Sample code:

```
    @application_checks.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    @slash_command(description="")
    async def ???(self, 
        interaction: nextcord.Interaction,
        title: str,
        description: str,
        field_name: str,
        field_value: str):
            embed = nextcord.Embed(
                title=title,
                description=description,
                color=0xffffff
            ) 
            embed.add_field(
                name=field_name, 
                value=field_value, 
                inline=False
            )
            await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)
```

[image]

Tried:

```
f"{description}"
format(description)
description.format
Etc...
```

Comment: If you want users to be able to add random stuff in your format strings (which is quite insecure), you'll have to manually parse that. You can't expect Python to fill in `interaction.guild.name`. That's just a string, you have to manually & explicitly provide the content. A small hint: `str.format()` can take a dict of `kwargs` to replace things with.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually set the embed description to the string you're creating.

```py
@application_checks.has_permissions(administrator=True)
@slash_command(description="")
async def ???(
    self, 
    interaction: nextcord.Interaction,
    title: str,
    description: str,
    field_name: str,
    field_value: str
):
    # not sure _how_ you want your description formatted - so just doing this for now
    formatted_description = f"{description} {field_name} {field_value}"

    embed = nextcord.Embed(
        title=title,
        description=formatted_description,
        color=0xffffff
    ) 
    embed.add_field(
        name=field_name, 
        value=field_value, 
        inline=False
    )
    
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)
```

So:

- format the description how you want to format it *before* creating the embed and save it as a variable
- use that variable as the embed description when you created the embed